# Proxmox LXC Networking with public IP

Tags: linux, networking, ip, proxmox, lxc

I have a bare-metal Proxmox server running with two public IPs. The initial configuration has already been done, and the containers are running with a NAT and a private network.

I currently have 2 public IPs:

190.140.147.92 (This is the available one)

This one has a comment in the interface that says *#route 190.140.147.64/26 via 190.140.147.65*

190.140.147.111 (this is the Proxmox one)

Apparently the person who did the initial setup did a nat masquerade with the available IP, and I need to use either one. I tried to do a bridge with each of the 2 ip's and it didn't work, it shows up.

```
icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

This is the current configuration

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface lo inet6 loopback

auto enp195s0
iface enp195s0 inet static
        address 190.140.147.92/26
        gateway 190.140.147.65
        up route add -net 190.140.147.64 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 190.140.147.65 dev enp195s0
# route 190.140.147.64/26 via 190.140.147.65

iface enp195s0 inet6 static
        address 9a01:4f8:261:1966::2/64
        gateway fe80::1

auto enxfe9a2a6a0631
iface enxfe9a2a6a0631 inet static
        address 190.140.147.111/26

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.1/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

        post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.0/24' -o enp195s0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.0/24' -o enp195s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I don't get where is the problem. Create bridge with that single physical interface, assign one IP to the bridge in the host. Put container NIC into that bridge and assign the second IP inside container; that would be assignment within the container configuration, not in the host interfaces file. Remember: any difference between "public" and "private" IP is on the BGP level (automatic routing between ISPs); there is absolutely no difference for you. Work with them exactly as with private IPs. You can test a setup using private IPs and then implement with public IPs,